# Docker and NGINX - host not found in upstream when building with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am attempting to use an NGINX container to host a static web application. This container should also redirect certain requests (i.e. www.example.com/api/) to another container on the same network.

I am getting the "host not found in upstream" issue when calling docker-compose build, even though I am enforcing that the NGINX container is the last to be built.

I have tried the following solutions:

- Enforcing a network name and aliases (as per [Docker: proxy_pass to another container - nginx: host not found in upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717835/docker-proxy-pass-to-another-container-nginx-host-not-found-in-upstream))
- Adding a "resolver" directive (as per [Docker Networking - nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639138/docker-networking-nginx-emerg-host-not-found-in-upstream/43127760#43127760) and others), both for 8.8.8.8 and 127.0.0.11.
- Rewriting the nginx.conf file to have the upstream definition before the location that will redirect to it, or after it.

I am running on a Docker for Windows machine that is using a mobylinux VM to run the relevant container(s). Is there something I am missing? It isn't obvious to me that the "http://webapi" address should resolve correctly, as the images are built but not running when you are calling docker-compose.

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream docker-webapi {
        server webapi:80;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root /wwwroot/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://docker-webapi;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapi:
    image: webapi
    build:
      context: ./src/Api/WebApi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile    
    volumes:
        - /etc/example/secrets/:/app/secrets/
    ports:
      - "61219:80"

  model.api:
    image: model.api
    build:
      context: ./src/Services/Model/Model.API
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - /etc/example/secrets/:/app/secrets/
    ports:
      - "61218:80"

  webapp:
    image: webapp
    build:
      context: ./src/Web/WebApp/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
        - webapi
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

RUN mkdir /wwwroot
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY wwwroot ./wwwroot/
EXPOSE 80
RUN service nginx start
```

Comment: Do you have a `nginx -t` to verify the config in your build? If so you shouldn't have it. Those will only be useful when the environment is up

Comment: Do you really get that error at build time????

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nope, not explicitly. I added the Dockerfile to the post.

Comment: @whites11 Yes, immediately upon calling the docker-compose build or docker-compose up --build commands, the first two images are built and the webapp image fails on the last step.

Comment: Could you post the output of `docker-compose build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is below

```
RUN service nginx start
```

You never run `service` command inside docker, because there is no init system. Also `RUN` commands are run during build time.

`nginx` original image has everything you need for nginx to start fine. So just remove the line and it would work.

By default nginx image has below `CMD` instruction

```
CMD ["nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"]
```

You can easily find that out by running the below command

```
docker history --no-trunc nginx | grep CMD
```